# Как экранировать [] в разделе see cref xml документации?

Tags: c#, xml, комментарии

Есть код c# с документацией:

```
/// <summary>
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// <see cref="Color[]"/>.
/// </returns>
public Color[] GetColors() {}
```

`VS` показывает syntax error для квадратных скобок <see cref="Color[]"/>.
При билде получается xml документация:

```
<member name="M:GetColors()">
    <summary>
    </summary>
    <returns>
    <see cref="!:Color[]"/>.
    </returns>
</member>
```

Знак ! указывает на ошибку, см. [Обработка XML-файла](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fsbx0t7x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Там должно быть что-то типа:

```
<see cref="T:Color[]"/>.
```

Проблема актуальна для ссылки `cref` раздела `see`, т.к. например в разделе `summary` можно свободно использовать скобки

Как можно экранировать эти квадратные скобки?

Comment: А что если в CDATA обернуть?

Comment: пробовал разные варианты, тег либо ссылки вообще на распознается, либо ошибка синтаксиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `T:Color[]`.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду в ручную корректировать генерируемый xml файл?

Comment: Я имел ввиду ссылаться данным образом непосредственно в xml-документации; см. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367493/how-to-refer-to-array-types-in-documentation-comments

Comment: Действительно, работает! Хотя редактор `Studio` говорит cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: В генерируемой документации типы выставляются неправильно. Получаем то, что написано, без корректировок, для "T:Color[]" получаем "T:Color[]" и т.д.  Вместо short[] мы должны получить System.In16[], вместо Color - System.Drawing.Color. Типы должны прописываться полными путями.